# why linux instead of windows because of ram?

Tags: linux, windows, heap-memory, ram

I'm trying to migrate an application from linux to Win and already I'm having a lot of difficulties with heap size, ram and ...
what is it about Ram that most people prefer to work on linux instead of Win?

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I know of is: you have a bug in your original code.

There are two main differences in managing memory:

1) Linear

Under Unix systems, you grow your heap as required and the addresses are therefore allocated linearly, increasing from the end of your data segment up. In most cases that is transparent. However, if you do reinterpret_cast<>() (or C-like casting) between pointers and integers, you may have problems there too (if you went from Linux 32 to Windows 64, for example.)

2) Clear

Windows clear the RAM (set it to all zeroes) in a different way than Linux. That's in most cases what causes grieves as you describe. This also applies to stack data.

In debug mode, also, Windows debug libraries, on purpose, set the RAM to different values (such as 0xCC or 0xFE). This is useful to detect bugs and it could very well be that you have bugs in your Linux version, only it "works" just because.

Also in regard to the stack, because the cl and gcc compilers do it completely differently, the stack is completely different. So the only thing you're seeing is that you have a bug in your original code...

Comment: It's actually worse than you give him credit for: he's using Java. None of his problems are even slightly related to the OS.

Comment: I did not see anything about the language used actually... I assumed it was C and/or C++. If it's Java... I have no clue. Maybe the Java environment is improperly setup... dunno much about Java other than I do not like it 8-).